# What is the usage of `retry` on Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.8, `retry` can be use like:

```
for i in 0..4
  puts i
  retry if i == 4
end
```

but in Ruby 1.9, it throw an error: Invalid retry, what is the usage of `retry` in Ruby 1.9? I can't find `retry` on http://www.ruby-doc.org =(

Comment: Why not try searching for `ruby + retry`? All sorts of hits come up on Google, which show the syntax for using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063166/what-is-the-purpose-of-redo-and-retry-statements-in-ruby/10064392#10064392

Answer (score 6):

It is for retrying failed operations (when you catch an exception)

```
n = 0
begin
  puts 'Trying to do something'
  raise 'oops'
rescue => ex
  puts ex
  n += 1
  retry if n < 3
end
puts "Ok, I give up"


# >> Trying to do something
# >> oops
# >> Trying to do something
# >> oops
# >> Trying to do something
# >> oops
# >> Ok, I give up
```

Comment: Where I can find the reference from official? =)

Comment: @WingLeong http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UM

Comment: Thanks, but this doc doesn't show how to use `retry` in rescue. =S

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, i believe retry would only work in a begin end block (or implicit begin end block in a method definition). Meaning it would jump back to begin. Not the beginning of a loop.
Also as of 1.9 retry only works in a rescue.

```
begin # should jump here
  for i in 4..0
    puts i
    4 / i
  end
rescue
  retry
end
```

I think what you are looking for is redo.

```
for i in 0..4
  puts i
  redo if i == 4
end
```

Be aware that redo will perform the last iteration again.
Results being:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4 # => infinite loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.9 supports `retry` in `begin rescue` clauses only.

You can use a continuation to replicate the behavior of the old `retry`

```
require 'continuation'

def with_retry
  loop { callcc { |cc| def cc.retry; call; end; yield cc; return }}
end

with_retry do |cc|
  for n in 1..4
    puts n
    cc.retry if n == 4
  end
end
```