# Ruby's redo method vs while loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop, redo

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063166/what-is-the-purpose-of-redo-and-retry-statements-in-ruby/10065957#10065957) and it got me thinking why one would want to use a while loop when the redo method could be used instead. I can't find any differentiation between the two. I know that the redo method will rerun the block of code, and that while loops will rerun the block of code as long as the conditional is true. Can someone give an example of why you'd want to use one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `redo` command restarts the current iteration of a loop (without checking termination conditions in `while` or advancing iterators in `for`, for example), you still *need* a loop of some description (such as a `while` loop).

That's evidenced by the answer you link to, which contains:

```
nums = Array.new(5){[rand(1..9), rand(1..9)]}
nums.each do |num1, num2|
  print "What is #{num1} + #{num2}: "
  redo unless gets.to_i == num1 + num2
end
```

The `.each` provides the looping structure there and all the `redo` does is restart that loop (without advancing to the next `nums` element) if you get the answer wrong.

Now you could actually *use* a `while` loop there as the controlling loop, advancing to the next one only if you get it *right:*

```
nums = Array.new(5){[rand(1..9), rand(1..9)]}
index = 0
while index < 6 do
    num1 = nums[index][0]
    num2 = nums[index][1]
    print "What is #{num1} + #{num2}: "
    if gets.to_i == num1 + num2 then
        index = index + 1
    end
end
```

or within the `.each` itself without `redo`:

```
nums = Array.new(5){[rand(1..9), rand(1..9)]}
nums.each do |num1, num2|
    answer = num1 + num2 + 1
    while answer != num1 + num2 do
        print "What is #{num1} + #{num2}: "
        answer = gets.to_i
    end
end
```

but neither of them are as elegant as the `redo` solution, which provides a more expressive way of controlling loops, an extension to the usual control you see in other languages, such as `continue` or `break`.

Comment: Good answer. Do you know if `redo` is widely used? Do you use it often? I've never had the need for it, preferring instead to loop with an enumerator or loop until I break out, but I'm just a hobbyist, so maybe I've been overlooking a useful tool.

Comment: @Cary, I don't use it _that_ often but I have used it, in a very similar case to the code given. When iterating over a collection where you have no control via an index, it's sometimes handy to be able to restart on the current collection element, if a temporary problem occurs (like user entering wrong data).